# How to search the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual?

Tags: search, info

Sometimes `describe-` or `apropos-` are not enough. How can I search the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual (<kbd>C-h i m elisp</kbd>) from within emacs?

Comment: As an aside, a shorter way to reach the elisp manual is `C-h r TAB RET`.

Comment: @legoscia: Uh, no. `C-h r` (command `info-emacs-manual`) reaches the **Emacs** manual, not the *Elisp* manual.

Comment: It does. However, the first link in the top node happens to lead to the Elisp manual, which is why the additional `TAB RET` brings you to the right place.

Comment: @legoscia: **`C-h i 5`** is shorter than both `C-h r TAB RET` and `C-h i m elisp RET`.

Comment: C-h i 5 isn't relevant. It takes you to "lists" if you're already in the top of the elisp manual and to something arbitrary if you are at the info top level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT**: I just found the wonderful `M-x info-apropos` which searches full text over all info documents and returns the relevant nodes. Seems this gem is relatively unknown.

If you use `helm` package from MELPA with `helm-mode` on, using either `i (info-index)` or `I (info-virtual-index)` pops up a helm window with the index terms. You can then use typical helm completion patterns to discover and browse the index.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `elisp-index-search`. I use it daily.
I use it mostly when I already know a function name and want to see it in emacs lisp manual.

Comment: Does this essentially do an info-apropos and jump to what it deems the best match?

Comment: I just tried info-apropos. It seems to search all info doc, but elisp-index-search only search elisp manual. I tried to find the doc for elisp-index-search but wasn't successful. I learned about it by calling describe-key on the menu 【Help→Search Documentation→Lookup Subject in Elisp Manual…】

Answer (score 6):

More of a full text search but <kbd>C-s</kbd> (`isearch-forward`) will search through the whole info document if you repeat enough times. I use it mostly as a desperation measure when I can't work out the actual term that appears in the index.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I know of is searching the index by running `Info-virtual-index` (bound to `I`) from within the manual.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have mentioned, [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) facilitates browsing and searching Info manuals.

1. Remember that `i` (`Info-index`) is your friend in Info. Start your search with it. It is typically more useful than a brute-force text search, because a human has indexed useful terms.

   Unfortunately, although `i` in vanilla index accepts a substring of an index entry as input (using `RET`), it does not provide substring, let along regexp, *completion*. In *Icicle* mode, `i` in Info is bound to `icicle-Info-index`, which provides such completion, and it also lets you filter using multiple patterns ([progressive completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion)). It is also a [multi-command](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands), which means that with a single `i` invocation you can visit any number of occurrences for any number of index entries.
2. With **Icicles**, you can optionally have `i` and other Info commands *highlight* a bit differently, in buffer `*Completions*`, completion candidates that correpond to Info *nodes that you have already visited*.  This is handy to avoid revisiting a node that you have already consulted, when searching in different ways.  It helps especially with double-entry indexing, that is, multiple index entries to the same node.
3. In addition to index lookup, you can *search* an Info manual. In vanilla Emacs you can use `C-s` or `C-M-s` repeatedly to do this. This can be handy in cases where `i` does give you the help you want.

   With **Icicles**, you can limit searching to a particular set of nodes.  `g` (`Info-goto-node`) accepts [multi-completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions) input.  You can provide a pattern (regexp, substring, etc.) that matches node names or a pattern that matches node content, or both.  Matching a pattern against node content means searching manual content. The completion candidates shown in `*Completions*` are the node names.

   You can search a set of nodes or an entire manual. After you choose one of the matching nodes to visit, you can use `C-M-s` to find each match of the content-search pattern within the node. And just as for `i`, `g` is a *multi-command*, which means that you can visit any number of nodes in a single `g` invocation.
4. You can create virtual books composed of different sets of nodes (even from different manuals), and save these persistently, for reuse later. Searching a smaller set of nodes (a sub-manual) can be faster.

See [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Info_Enhancements) for more info about **Icicles** Info enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `s` to search the current document for the next instance of a given regular expression.  Repeated presses of `s-<RET>` will iteratively search for the next instance of the same expression.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/info/Search-Text.html#Search-Text

Answer (score 0):

### Go to EmacsDocs.org

Go to **[emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Emacs-Lisp](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Emacs-Lisp)** where they've republished the Emacs Lisp docs in a readable way and added a decent full-text search engine to query its contents.

You can find the source on GitHub at **[tefkah/emacs-docs](https://github.com/tefkah/emacs-docs)**.